# Get list of new commits between two tags in Git?

Tags: git

I'm writing a script in Perl to extract the differences between the present release label (or tag) and the previous one. I was using ClearCase to do this with this command,

```
cleartool diff -columns 150 <old_label> <new_label> 2> /dev/null
```

which would give me the complete commit details of who all did what.

Now, we are shifting to Git. Hence, I want to know how do we do this with Git? I did the below:

```
git diff <old_git_tag> <new_git_tag>
```

But I'm not getting the commits details. Please help on how to get only the commits from previous label and present label.

Comment: `git diff %old_tag%..%new_tag%` for code difference, `git log %old_tag%..%new_tag%` for commits, no?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Different commits between two branches](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7566416/456814).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git log between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136178/git-log-between-tags)

Answer (score 3):

To obtain all the `commits` between one label/tag to other use,

`git log <old_label>..<new_label>`

To obtain all the `changes` between the two labels use

`git diff <old_label>..<new_label>`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want commit informations, you could use

```
git log --oneline --graph <old_label>..<new_label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git rev-list <old_label>..<new_label>
```

will give you a list of commit ids and just commit ids (no log info for example).