# How to extract different file versions between two tags in Git?

Tags: git

Methods like mentioned here [Get list of new commits between two tags in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194506/difference-between-two-tags-in-git) gives me list of diff files.

However, I have a constraint like I can't checkout every time to a tag because I need to serve more than 1000 request/sec asking diff files between different tags. Is there any method available to achieve this?

For example, I have 3 tags:

- 1.0
- 1.1
- 1.2

Now assume a file `one.txt` changes in all tags and head is on latest tag (1.2). Now when I do

```
git diff 1.0 1.1 --stat
```

it returns me file name `one.txt` so now I know that `one.txt` is changed, and I can grab that file. However, to get `one.txt` on tag 1.1, I need to checkout first at 1.1, otherwise I will get latest `one.txt`, so here I need to avoid that checkout and get the `one.txt` as it was on 1.1.

Please suggest any solution?

Comment: What do you mean by a "diff file"? What is that supposed to be?

Comment: i mean files changed, not the diff at code level. Mostly i will be dealing with the binary files. so need only files those are changed between tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1: `git checkout`

Using `git checkout` with a revision specifier like a branch, tag, or commit sha, along with a filepath, will checkout that revision of the file into your working copy:

```
git checkout <tag> -- <filepath>
```

Note that this only modifies the version of that one particular file. The rest of your working copy will not be affected.

#### Documentation

From the [official Linux Kernel documentation for `git log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) (summarized):

> ```
> git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…
> ```
>
> When `<paths>` or `--patch` are given, `git checkout` does **not** switch branches. It updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file or from a named `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit)...The `<tree-ish>` argument can be used to specify a specific tree-ish (i.e. commit, tag or tree) to update the index for the given paths before updating the working tree.

### Solution 2: `git show`

You can also retrieve a version of a file using `git show` and outputting the results to a file:

```
git show <tag>:<filepath> > <outputPath>
```

### See Also

Official Linux Kernel documentation for:

- [`git log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html)
- [`git show`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html)
- [What are commit-ish and tree-ish in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303549/what-are-commit-ish-and-tree-ish-in-git/23303550#23303550)