# How to make the changelog after " --- " delimiter in git

Tags: git, patch

How can I make the changelog in git format as following ?
All the changelogs V1->V2 ... are after "---"

```
    Signed-off-by: xxx 
    ---
    Changes in v2:
    - xxx xxx xxx
    Changes in v3:
    - xxx xxx xxx

     drivers/media/platform/sh_veu.c | 4 ++--
     1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need some kind of changelog generator, like [**`git-chglog/git-chglog`**](https://github.com/git-chglog/git-chglog).

If not, at the very least, try a [log between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8136213/6309):

```
git log --oneline tag1..tag2
```